# Error: Unable to locate package gcc-10 while updating GCC and G++

Tags: apt, gcc, g++

Hi i am trying to update gcc and g++ on my Ubuntu 18.04. I currently have version 7.5 of both gcc and g++. I found this article where it is written that we can install a gcc and g++ version via a command:

```
sudo apt install gcc-8 g++-8 gcc-9 g++-9 gcc-10 g++-10
```

So i want to update to version 10 only and so i tried

```
sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
```

But then i get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'clang-10-examples' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'clang-10' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'libclang-10-dev' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'python-clang-10' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'clang-10-doc' for regex 'g++-10'
Note, selecting 'python3-clang-10' for regex 'g++-10'
E: Unable to locate package gcc-10
```

My questions are:

1. How can i resolve this problem and update the gcc and g++ version to 10?
2. How can i install the version 10 of gcc and g++ without removing my older 7.5 version so that if anything goes wrong i can make the old one default. That is have both versions 7.5 and 10 side by side.
3. How can i update to the newer 10 version of both g++ and gcc and also remove the older version 7.5 so that i only have the newer version? Btw is there any possiblity of system not booting up bacause of this update(due to some missing headers or other older files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely expected.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not have gcc-10 package. It is available only since 20.04 LTS.

See https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gcc-10 for details and make a bookmark for https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to ease package search next time.

---

If you do not care about package origin, then you can try to install the package from some [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enetext/+archive/ubuntu/paczki?field.series_filter=bionic).

Comment: Is there a way to install the required version(10 or 11) of gcc and g++ from official sources instead of thrid-party PPA?

Comment: No, use packages from PPA.

Comment: So if i upgrade to Ubuntu 20.08 will i be able to install gcc and g++ 10 from official sources?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has gcc-10 as described on https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gcc-10 . If you need gcc-11 - install 21.04 in Docker or VM.